# Python : File with one JSON obj on each line

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

Greetings from tokyo.

Let me explain you what i'm trying to achieve with python 2.7 :

I have a file with a **JSON Dict** on each line, here is a capture :

```
1 {"res":0, "res_message":"OK", "debug_info":{"id-info":"9089"}, "visits":[{"id":"237000080507750613","siteId":1551642,"startTime":1483217576324,"endTime":1483217696000,"clientIPs":["69.61.12.70"],"country"    :["United States"],"countryCode":["US"],"clientType":"Vulnerability Scanner","clientApplication":"Grabber","clientApplicationId":780,"httpVersion":"1.1","clientApplicationVersion":"null","userAgent":"Mozi    lla/5.0 CommonCrawler Node 3AEHGF7VNEKJUWOPKJJIJ7ODKPM4XXVZQUTHNWS5B2O5AEAGHIG4HVC42LLEUSO.CQYXO3ZFD.GB5RZ5EG2SRWW335PUSOSIVLZUXPCTJUGV2MDJGQJDJPE5UH.cdn0.common.crawl.zone","os":"","osVersion":"","suppor    tsCookies":false,"supportsJavaScript":false,"hits":1,"pageViews":0,"entryReferer":"","servedVia":["Ashburn,VA"],"securitySummary": {"api.threats.bot_access_control":1},"actions":[{"postData":"","requestResult":"api.request_result.req_blocked_security","isSecured":false,"responseTime":0,"thinkTime":0,"incidentId":"237000080507750613-304992946328    764549","threats":[{"securityRule":"api.threats.bot_access_control","alertLocation":"api.alert_location.alert_location_path","attackCodes":["200.0"],"securityRuleAction    ":"api.rule_action_type.rule_action_block"}]}]}, ...

2 {"res":0, "res_message":"OK", "debug_info":{"id-info":"9089"}, "visits":[{"id":"520000110618442601","siteId":1551642,"startTime":1482666233524,"endTime":1482666353000,"clientIPs":["93.175.201.18"],"countr    y":["Ukraine"],"countryCode":["UA"],"clientType":"Spam Bot","clientApplication":"DTS Agent","clientApplicationId":99,"httpVersion":"1.1","clientApplicationVersion":"null","userAgent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compati    ble; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt; DTS Agent","os":"","osVersion":"","supportsCookies":false,"supportsJavaScript":false,"hits":1,"pageViews":0,"entryReferer":"","served    Via":["Warsaw, Poland"],"securitySummary":{"api.threats.bot_access_control":1},"actions":[{"postData":"","requestResult":"api.request_result.req_blocked_security","isSecured":false,"responseTime":2,"thinkTime":1,"incidentId":"520000110618442601-1233371267206742195","threats":[{"securityRule":"api.threats.bot_access_control","alertLocation":"api.alert_location.alert_location_path","attackCodes":["200.0"],"securityRuleAction":"api.rule_action_type.rule_action_block"}]}]}, ...

3 {"res":0, "res_message":"OK", "debug_info":{"id-info":"9089"}, "visits":[{"id":"520000110602830007","siteId":1551642,"startTime":1482429957001,"endTime":1482430077000,"clientIPs":["93.175.201.18"],"countr    y":["Ukraine"],"countryCode":["UA"],"clientType":"Spam Bot","clientApplication":"DTS Agent","clientApplicationId":99,"httpVersion":"1.1","clientApplicationVersion":"null","userAgent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compati    ble; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt; DTS Agent","os":"","osVersion":"","supportsCookies":false,"supportsJavaScript":false,"hits":1,"pageViews":0,"entryReferer":"","served    Via":["Warsaw, Poland"],"securitySummary":{"api.threats.bot_access_control":1},"actions":[{"postData":"","requestResult":"api.request_result.req_blocked_security","isSecured":false","responseTime":4,"thinkTime":4,"incidentId":"520000110602830007-3073954101470953658","threats":[{"securityRule":"api.threats.bot_access_control","alertLocation":"api.alert_location.alert_location_path","attackCodes":["200.0"],"securityRuleAction":"api.rule_action_type.rule_action_block"}]}]}, ...
```

I tried to proceed the whole file with `json.loads()` , without any success.

Here is my **code**

```
g = open('monthlyLogShort.txt', 'w')
with open("page.txt") as f:
         data = f.read()
         parse = json.loads(data)        # <-load the JSON dict
         field_list = parse["visits"]
         for fields in field_list:       # <-extract the the following field
                 print >> g , "visit_id=",(fields["id"]),",","src_country=",(fields["country"]),",", "event_timestamp=",(fields["startTime"]),",","src_ip=",(fields["clientIPs"]),",","dest_name=", rwdname,"    ,","dest_id=",(fields["siteId"]),",","signature=",(fields["securitySummary"])
g.close()
```

As you can imagine, i can parse only one line with this code.
What is the best (pythonic) approach to proceed the whole file ?

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the number of lines is always the same i came up with this solution :

```
g = open('monthlyLogShort.txt', 'w')
with open('page.txt','r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        countp = 0
        page = 0
        while countp < 10:
                parse = json.loads(data[page])  # load the JSON dict
                field_list = parse["visits"]
                for fields in field_list:       # extract the the following field
                        print >> g , "visit_id=",(fields["id"]),",","src_country=",(fields["country"]),",", "event_timestamp=",(fields["startTime"]),",","src_ip=",(fields["clientIPs"]),",","dest_name=", dname,",","dest_id=",(fields["siteId"]),",","signature=",(fields['securitySummary'])
                countp = countp + 1
                page = page + 1
        else:
                g.close()
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The file as a whole is not a valid JSON, but you can parse it *line by line*:

```
with open("page.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        obj = json.loads(line.split(" ", 1)[1])
        print(obj["visits"])
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply alecxe. Will try this stuff tomorrow at work and accept the answer if it goes well ! : )

Comment: Still got a parsing error : ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 14 - line 2 column 1 (char 13 - 121954)

Comment: @Emka are you sure there are valid json strings after the first space on every line? Also, are there any other space delimited values after the JSON string? Thanks.

Comment: Im pretty sure that the json strings are valid. Before the Visits key, there is 3 spaces. 

After the visits Key , there is tons of spaces inside the values, but not outside.